# Should my question be CW? I have not received any answers yet.

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I am trying to get answers for [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/653885/lecture-notes-in-real-analysis) using the standard MSE way, which is letting users receive a reputation award if they post a quality answer. But by making it a CW within minutes, it appears that my question is destined to be swept under the rug. I flagged it but it has not received any attention yet.

[Lecture Notes in Real Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/653885/lecture-notes-in-real-analysis)

Comment: Maybe instead of complaining about the CW stamp, you should explain what you expect your thread to contain that the linked general lecture note collection thread could not.

Answer (score 6):

Your question was made CW because it is a request for a list of sources and thus is not definitively answerable.  Making a post CW is a judgement on the content and format of a question, not a disincentive to answer it.  If people are interested in your question, they will answer it whether it is worth reputation or not.

Comment: don't mean to be disrespectful but rep rewards good answers and is an incentive. non cw answers are more likely to be given attention

Comment: @grayQuant: you're new around here, aren't you?

Comment: @grayQuant Rep is an incentive, but CW questions are [certainly not](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list?sort=votes&pageSize=15) less likely to receive attention.  If you want more answers, try focusing your efforts on improving your question, rather than blaming the system.  Even if your question is already good, you can always make it better, anywhere from refining what you're asking for, including more research, or just editing your tone to be more interesting to read.  Take a look at some of the highly upvoted questions within the tags that interest you as examples.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I would point out that quite a few questions on that list were converted to CW automatically *because* they received so much attention (i.e. 31 answers); but the point still stands.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have been here for over a year but there's a lot of site mechanics I still don't know about.

Answer (score 0):

You asked the question yesterday. It's way too early to call your question "swept under the rug". If you feel it does not get the attention it needs after 2 days pass you will be able to [add a bounty in order to increase incentive](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).

In the mean time you ought to consider other potential issues with the question. For example on SE sites it is usually more productive to ask a question about the subject matter yourself that you know could only come from the kind of sources you are trying to trace. This sort of question is much more interesting to experts, more likely to be of use to future visitors, and good answers to such questions will reference the material you were looking for in the first place.

Comment: I am looking for study material for a course, real analysis in this case. I am sure a collection will be useful to many other people, esp after seeing the other reference request questions. But I am done with this issue, obviously no mod will reverse the decision.

Comment: @grayQuant Perhaps you are asking on the wrong site. SE sites are not equally good for all kinds of questions, and resource requests are not something it caters to. If you still think it fits, an effort to make the system work with and for you rather than trying to fight it would be the most productive. Try answering some other questions so you have a chunk of rep to dish out in a bounty.